# Install R-project on splunk

Tags: r, splunk

I am trying  to install  ['R Analytics'](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3339/) in [splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) (I am using Windows 10 (64-bit) operating system).

I installed the 'R Analytics' app in splunk and 'OpenCPU' package in R. Unfortunately Run button in Script Editor does not work. I also found that 'runrdo' command is also unknow but 'runrdo' is in 'commandsconf' in splunk. How to fix this? I add some photo to ensure every thing is installed correctly.

1. First install 'OpenCPU' package and run 'opencpu::ocpu_start_server()'

[image]

2. install 'R Analytics' (r-analytics_101.tgz) [splunk](https://www.splunk.com/)

[image]

The 'R Project' appeared as follows shown:

[image]

Now I am trying to use script editor

[image]

I can see the splunk can send request to Rstudio (Show installed packages correctly)

[image]

But unfortunately RUN button does not work.

[image]

When I want to use 'runrdo':

[image]

But it is in  'commandsconf'

[image]

Sample code from https://community.splunk.com/t5/Getting-Data-In/connecting-Rest-API-from-R/m-p/204018 worked for me with R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) and Splunk version 8.2.3.

I found there is nothing  wrong with the installations steps. I think the problem is on the difference between python 2.7 and python 3.7. The Splunk R-app is too old and written in python 2.7. The most recent version of Splunk is using python 3.7. I installed the Splunk 7.3.9(that use python 2.7), https://download.splunk.com/products/splunk/releases/7.3.9/windows/splunk-7.3.9-39a78bf1bc5b-x64-release.msi, and all features except The Run button works fine as follows shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://community.splunk.com did you try to ask there?